# how to write media query for 3840x2160

Tags: css, responsive

I want to develop a responsive web page using media queries. I have also wrote media queries for mobile, tables & desktops.

How to write the css code for device max-width:3840px

I am confused whether this is the correct way of writing media queries as i am writing the same set of css code for each & every device size again & again.

Please help me to proceed furthur as i am new to media queries. And also i am confused whether to go for adaptive layout or responsive layout?

Comment: `max-width` will be always satisfied, I'd guess the CSS snippet for 3840x2160 should go with `min-width` (but it depends how you declared rules for lower resolutions...then I have to say, share your code) About _"And also i am confused whether to go for adaptive layout or responsive layout?"_. Way too broad. It's not (only) a technical decision.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 3840px) {
 /*your css definition */
 /* example: */
 main.div {border: 1px solid red; }
}
```

Attenion!: The css for this width is wrapped into curly braces, as written below.

If you want to declare a range use the following syntax:

```
@media (min-width: 2120px) and (max-width: 3840px) {
 /*your css definition */
 /* example: */
 main.div {border: 1px solid red; }
}
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries